# two dimensional Arrays access using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Is

```
 *(ary[3]+8)
```

and

```
 ary[3][8]
```

are the same ? If yes, please explain how ? ary[3] returns the address of first element or the value in ary[3][0] ? ary is a two dimensional array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can access also it like this: `*(*(ary+ 3) + 8)`. Note that `ary[3]` is the same as `*(ary + 3)`. This should answer your question.

Comment: The value at *(ary+3) and ary[3] are the same. What does *(ary+3) return ? The value at ary[3][0] or the starting address of ary[3] ?

Comment: @StoryTeller : ary is 2d array. Can you please share your knowledge on this ?

Comment: @SriniVas, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14111286/817643 about what defining a true 2d array means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

`a[i]` is same as `*(a+i)`

`ary[i][j]` is same as `*( *(ary+i)+j))`

Comment: Doesn't *(ary+i) in *(*(ary+i)+j)) return value at ary[i] ? Pointer holds an address and * is to retrieve the value at the address. Going by this, *(ary+i) has to return the value in ary+i. And we add j to the value at the address ary+i and change the value at the address obtained from the previous step. Isn't that how it has to work or works ?

Comment: I do not see a contradiction in the previous Srini Vas's comment. He says pointer holds and address and * is to retrive the value at the address. The value, in this case, is a pointer to a (1dim) array.

Comment: @StoryTeller: What is a counterexample?

Comment: A true 2d array `a[2][3]`, when indexed, expands into `*(a + 2i + j)`.
The size is part of the type. What banarun said is only true when `a` is a one dimensional array of pointers.

Comment: @StoryTeller: It's *always* the case that `a[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(a+i) + j)`.  For a true 2D array, this is *also* equivalent to `*((T*)a + 3*i + j)` (where `T` is the type of each element).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, if that's the case, `*(a+i)` must be a pointer type. What type is it?

Comment: @StoryTeller: If you have `T a[M][N]`, then `*(a+i)` is of type `T[N]`, which decays to `T*` in most situations.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, ignore the deleted comment. I removed it for a reason :)

Answer (score 1):

`*(ary[3]+8)` says value at 8th column of third row.`ary[3]` is base address of third Row.`ary[3][8]` will also access to same element at third row and 8th column.

For Example i am taking an 2D array of two row and 4 column which is equivalent to 1D array of 8 elements.As shown below.

int a[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int b[2][4] = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}};

since `b` is 2D array , so you can consider it as array of two 1D arrays.when you pass b[1] or b[1][0] it says address of first row.Rectangular array allocated in memory by Row.so if you want to find address of element a[row][col] it will get calculated as

`address = baseAddress + elementSize * (row*(total number of column) + col);`

Comment: Where/How in memory is the base array of ary[3] is stored? ary[0..n][0..n] are stored sequentially. ary[3] and ary[3][0] has to have the same base address and how is it resolved when invoked by calls of above types?

Comment: @SriniVas Edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: @SriniVas Aha, this is what you mean. The values of `ary[i]` are not stored anywhere if your array is declared as e.g. `int ary[4][9]`. The compiler knows that your `ary` is a two-dimensional array, and when you do `ary[i]` this gives the address you say. But note that the following example is completely different case: `int *ary[4]; 
  int ary1[9]; 
  int ary2[9]; 
  int ary3[9]; 
  int ary4[9]; 
  
  ary[0] = ary1; 
  ary[1] = ary2; 
  ary[2] = ary3; 
  ary[3] = ary4;`  although you can indeed call this a 2d array as well. Here, the pointers to the second dimension are explicitly stored.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is an array (`int`, say) `x[i]` is just a syntactic sugar for `*(x+i)`. In your case, `ary` is a two-dimensional array (again of `int`, say). By the same syntactic sugar mechanism, `ary[i][j]` is equivalent to `*((*(ary+i))+j)`, from which it is clear what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

As others already have said, `a[i]` is just a sugar for `*(a+i)`.

I just would like to add that it always works, that allows us to do things like that:

```
char a[10];
char b;
char c[10][20];

// all of these are the same:
b = a[5];      // classic
b = *(a + 5);  // pointer shifting
b = 5[a];      // even so!

b = c[5][9];
b = *(c[5] + 9);
b = *(*(c + 5) + 9);
b = *(c + 5)[9];
b = 5[c][9];
b = 5[9][c];  // WRONG! Compiling error
```