# The outputs of my program are confusing

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have code something like this

```
int main () 
 { 
     unsigned int x [4] [3] = 
     {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
     printf("%u, %u, %u", x + 3, * (x + 3), * (x + 2) + 3); 
 }
```

The output for all of the 3 values are same can anyone tell me why.?

Comment: Using the wrong format specifier is undefined behaviour.

Comment: How come wrong format specifier %u is for unsigned int.

Comment: `x+3` has type `unsigned int (*)[3]` (a pointer),`*(x+3)` and `*(x+2)+3` have type `unsigned int *`. All 3 are no `unsigned int`, but pointers, so you should use `%p` and cast to `(void*)`.

Comment: @PrajwalBhat, to answer your comment about array indexing being pointer arithmetic in disguise: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14111286/817643

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - as others have pointed out - you need to use the correct format specifiers, and cast to these values to pointers.

---

Now as to why all of them give same value.

Here x is an array. And the type of its elements are `unsigned int[3]`. i.e. `x` is an array
of `unsigned int[3]` arrays.

First, `x + 3` 
gives the address of fourth element in your array. That is the
address of `{10, 11, 12}`. The address of this array in memory will be the address of its first element in memory. That is the address of `10` in memory. Note that this value is `int (*) [3]`, i.e. `address of an unsigned int[3] array`.

Second, `* (x + 3)`
is equivalent to x[3], which is the fourth element, which is `unsigned int[3]`.
It is the array `{10, 11, 12}`. This value is pointing to the first element of
array `{10, 11, 12}`. That is, this value is pointing to `10`. Note that this value is `unsigned int[3]`.

Third `*(x+2) + 3` : Here `*(x + 2)` is equivalent to `x[2]` which is an `unsigned int[3]`, which is `{7, 8, 9}` array ,
and when you do a `+ 3` you are again getting the address of `10`. Note that this value is `unsigned int[3]`.

So, you see in all three cases your result is the same address in memory, i.e. the address where `10` is stored - even though you are representing different things at different time; `unsigned int (*)[3]` at first, and `unsigned int[3]` at second and third.

Answer (score 0):

Distilled undefined behavior:

```
printf("%u, %u, %u", x + 3, * (x + 3), * (x + 2) + 3);
```

All extra arguments must be `unsigned int`, but the 2d is `unsigned int (*)[3]`, the 3d is `unsigned int *`, the 4th is `unsigned int *` too.

Answer (score 0):

You get wrong values because you do the pointer arithmetic wrong.
`x` is of type  `unsigned int[4][3]`, an array of length 4, each member of which is itself an array of length 3.

So what is `x+3`? It's the address of the last member in `x` (remember that the members of `x` are **arrays**).
And therefore `*(x+3)` is itself an array. But what happens to arrays when you pass them as function parameters? They decay into pointers. So you see the address of the first element in *that* array, mangled by the wrong type specifier in `printf`.

Okay, let's get to element `x[2][3]` for instance. It will be an expression of this sort `*(*(x+2)+3)` which is all in all equivalent to `*(&x[0][0] + 2*3 + 3)`.